# Removing old name /tmp/docview1000 warning

Tags: debugging, docview

When starting emacs I get the following warning:

```
Warning (initialization): an error occurred while loading '/home/jamesbond/.emacs':

File error: Removing old name, no such file or directory, /tmp/docview1000
```

Using --debug-init returns:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Removing old name" "no such file or directory" "/tmp/docview1000")
  delete-file("/tmp/docview1000" nil)
  dired-delete-file("/tmp/docview1000" always)
  doc-view-clear-cache()
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-811718> nil "/home/jamesbond/.emacs.d/settings/general-settings.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 5446
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/jamesbond/.emacs.d/settings/general-settings.el" "/home/jamesbond/.emacs.d/settings/general-settings.el" nil t)
  require(general-settings)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/jamesbond/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 346
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/jamesbond/.emacs" "/home/jamesbond/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Emacs is also not behaving according to some of my settings anymore. Maybe they are not reached due to the error? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by commenting the line

```
(doc-view-clear-cache)
```

in my settings.